# Typescript 2 types with react-router, cannot find name path, component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Screenshots kind of speak for themselves, first this is my routes file where the problem occur, you can see the unused import and path and component not being found.

[image]

Here is my package.json with the types dependencies and the @types in the node_modules folder.

[image]

Finally, my configs

[image]
[image]

I cannot get where is the problem here, anyone got something similar?

Note that I've been able to use `<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />` and react and redux object in the app without problems.

Comment: I faced something similar problem while working with typescript, react-router. had to resort to DefinitlyTyped version - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/60e56c268fa43cee750cd410275f6d32dd4cf478/react-router

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `routes` file has a `.ts` extension but should be `.tsx` if it contains JSX.